# How to generate a coverage report with vscode extension tests

Tags: testing, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, test-coverage

I'm implementing a VSCode extension. I set up the project following [this link](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension).

It generates a starter project with a `src/test/runTest.ts` file:

```
import * as path from 'path';

import { runTests } from '@vscode/test-electron';

async function main() {
    try {
        // The folder containing the Extension Manifest package.json
        // Passed to `--extensionDevelopmentPath`
        const extensionDevelopmentPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../../');

        // The path to test runner
        // Passed to --extensionTestsPath
        const extensionTestsPath = path.resolve(__dirname, './suite/index');

        // Download VS Code, unzip it and run the integration test
        await runTests({ extensionDevelopmentPath, extensionTestsPath });
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Failed to run tests');
        process.exit(1);
    }
}

main();
```

And a command in the `package.json`:

```json
{
    "compile": "tsc -p ./",
    "pretest": "npm run compile && npm run lint",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext ts",
    "test": "node ./out/test/runTest.js"
}
```

Is there a way to generate a coverage report with it?

Comment: that is probably a debugger feature to inject calls to `line X is executing` for each and every line it reaches, attach an event handler to this, or subscribe to the event, is done by the test runner

Answer (score 5):

VSCode extension unittesting uses [Mocha](https://mochajs.org/) under the hood. You can generate coverage reports like in any other Typescript/Javascript project using one of the many available frameworks, e.g. [c8](https://github.com/bcoe/c8), [jest](https://jestjs.io/), [istanbul](https://istanbul.js.org/), etc.

Install the framework of your choice, here I use `c8`

```bash
npm i --save-dev c8
```

and add to scripts

```json
  "scripts": {
    "compile": "tsc -p ./",
    "pretest": "npm run compile && npm run lint",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext ts",
    "test": "node ./out/test/runTest.js",
    "coverage": "c8 --check-coverage npm run test"
  }
```

Depending on your extension you might need to create a configuration file with the files you want to check for coverage. Here we are checking the compiled `.js` files placed under the `out/` dir and we also excluding the files responsible for unittesting i.e. `out/test/` (usually).

`.c8rc`

```json
{
  "all": true,
  "include": ["out/**"],
  "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**", "out/test/"],
  "reporter": ["html", "text"]
}
```

Run the `coverage` script and you should get an output of your coverage

```bash
npm run coverage
```

[image]

A working repo making use of the above: https://github.com/fortran-lang/vscode-fortran-support

Comment: I have tried this but it gives error in windoes 11
```[main 2023-02-02T15:18:05.015Z] UtilityProcess<1>: Waiting for extension host with pid 13300 to exit.
[main 2023-02-02T15:18:05.124Z] UtilityProcess<1>: received exit event with code 0.
[main 2023-02-02T15:18:05.124Z] Extension host with pid 13300 exited with code: 0, signal: .
Exit code:   0
Done
```

Comment: The error message alone does not provide enough info as to what's going on. A guess would that when you run with coverage you are hitting the default time limit set in Mocha. Have a look at a working example and maybe try and create something similar: https://github.com/fortran-lang/vscode-fortran-support

Comment: I want this to run continuously in VS Code like a linter, and in the line number section of the currently open file, any lines that aren't covered would be highlighted red. Is there an extension for this?

Comment: Figured it out using [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=markis.code-coverage) and [this config](https://github.com/bcoe/c8/issues/71#issuecomment-504710008) (I had to change `"report-dir": "./.coverage",` to `"report-dir": "./coverage",` to remove the leading dot)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [vscode-test-cli](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-test-cli), which is now the default when creating a new extension via `yo code`, it is very easy.

Install the dependency of `@vscode/test-cli`, if not already in the project.

```
npm install --save-dev @vscode/test-cli
```

Then you can generate the coverage with the following command.

```
vscode-test --coverage
```

Note: Your version should be at least 0.0.6.

You can also set the output directory of the coverage with `--coverage-output` (default: [temp dir of OS](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-test-cli/blob/f177580028a30ff518c1a7426fe0dbe19c6d3e69/src/cli/coverage.mts#L23)) and `--coverage-reporter` (any mocha reporters possible).

That means if you want to generate the coverage in your coverage directory with text and html reporter, you can use the following.

```
vscode-test --coverage --coverage-output ./coverage --coverage-reporter html --coverage-reporter text"
```

---

**old solution with @vscode/test-cli version 0.0.4**

1. Install c8

```
npm install --save-dev c8
```

2. Add a coverage script to your `package.json`:

```
"coverage": "c8 npm run test"
```

3. Run the coverage via `npm run coverage`.

In my case, additional configuration was not needed.